# Equivalent of a 404 for a websocket

Tags: java-websocket, jsr356

I am using websockets to pass information about a resource from the server to the client.  The websocket Endpoint uses a pathparam to identify the specific resource.  For example:

```
@ServerEndpoint("/resources/{resource-id}/updates")
```

The Endpoint class has the following logic in its `onOpen` method:

```
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(@PathParam("resource-id")int resourceId, Session session) throws IOException {
     boolean resourceExists = checkIfResourceExists(resourceId);
     if (!resourceExists) {
         // what should I do here?
     }
}
```

When using AJAX long-polling, I'd send a 404 response if the resource doesn't exist.  The client would then know not to try again.  Is there an equivalent technique to use for websockets?  My two thoughts are:

1. Use the following code in the `if (!resourceExists)` block, above:

   `session.close(new CloseReason(CUSTOM_NOT_FOUND_CODE, "Resource ID not found"));
    return;`

   Where `CUSTOM_NOT_FOUND_CODE` is a CloseCode in the 4000-4999 range.
2. Perform this logic somewhere in the `ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator` implementation for this Endpoint and return a 404 there before the connection upgrade occurs.  This sounds like the best approach to me, but there doesn't appear to be any way to send a standard HTTP error response from the `modifyHandshake` method.
3. Perform this logic in a Filter.  The problem here, though, is if I load the resource in the filter, how do I pass it to the Endpoint?  With an HTTP request, I can add a request attribute in a filter which is then available in the servlet.  But there doesn't seem to be an easy way to achieve the same thing with websockets.  I could, of course, load the resource again in the Endpoint class, but that's duplication of work.

I'm sure this must be a common scenario, so is there an accepted best-practice approach here?

Comment: A WebSocket connection starts out as a regular HTTP request and gets upgraded to WebSocket if the server agrees to it. So, if a WebSocket tries to connect to a URL that does not exist, the correct solution would be to send a standard HTTP 404 response to fail the upgrade handshake. Or am I missing something? Is your WebSocket already connected and you are sending a command that the server would send a reply to? If that is the case, then you are implementing a custom protocol on top of WebSocket, so just send an error reply in your own format and leave the WebSocket connected for more commands.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, you are right:  I want to be able to send a standard 404 *before* the upgrade request is completed.  But there doesn't seem to be a way to do that using Java's websocket implementation as there's no way to hook into the request before it gets upgraded to a websocket without using a filter, but that has limitations, too (I'll update the question with the limitations of that approach).